# Microphone start recording sound

Tags: android, ios

I would like to make UX of sound recording the same on Android and iOS platform but while there is a sound effect at the beginning and ending of a recording on Android there is none on iOS.

1. How to disable it on Android?
2. How to enable it on iOS? Do I need "manually" play a sound?

On Android I use `SpeechRecognizer` class and on iOS it's `AVAudioEngine` and `SFSpeechRecognizer`.

Answer (score 1):

To disable it on Android, you have to mute notification sounds on your Application. You can initiate it on the MainActivity using following code. This is what we do usually when we need our own "mic on, mic off" sound. But keep in mind that there is a latency attached to it when playing your own sounds manually.

```
AudioManager mAudio = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
mAudio.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, AudioManager.ADJUST_MUTE, 0);
```